# EntityFramework 6 not found in NuGet Package Manager

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am attempting to use EntityFramework 6.1.3 on a machine that is connected to an intranet, so the NuGet Package Manager is unable to download packages.

I have installed EntityFramework 6.1.3 from the .msi, but it is NOT displaying in the package manager as installed and I cannot use the ADO.NET Entity Data Model without receiving an error.

When I attempt to set up a connection with the Entity Data Model Wizard, at the "Choose Your Version" screen, Entity Framework 6.x is selected and greyed out, with the error "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. If you have already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before preforming this action."

I am running Visual Studio 2013 Professional with Oracle Developer Tools 12.1.0.2.4 installed.

I have searched for an answer to my problem, but I have had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your Entity Framework from version 6 to 5. In Package Manager Console, write:

```
Uninstall-package EntityFramework
Install-Package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [NuGet package file, store it locally and use the local folder as source for nuget](http://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/).

[image]

[image]

[image]
*(see package source is set to use the local repository)*

The Error Message:

> "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework;
>   however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this
>   version could not be found for your data connection. If you have
>   already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your
>   project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit this wizard,
>   install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before
>   preforming this action."

means you reference an old EF4/5 provider. YOu need to reference an EF6 provider

Comment: Thanks for the response! EntityFramework is now installed, but I am still receiving the same error when trying to "Choose Your Version".  Any suggestions?

Comment: post the error message. Also make sure you use EF6 Oracle Provider and not the old 4/5 one

Comment: Error Message:  "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework; however, an Entity Framework database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection. If you have already installed a compatible provider, ensure you have rebuilt your project before performing this action. Otherwise, exit this wizard, install a compatible provider, and rebuild your project before preforming this action."

Comment: ok, so it is a provider issue. reference an EF6 Oracle provider

Comment: My apologies, but can you explain how to do that? I have installed the following NuGet packages: "Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver" and "Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Entity Framework Driver" but still no luck. I also added the references to "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.121.20" and "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.2.0"

Comment: Not sure what was causing the issue, but after I installed the NuGet packages "EntityFramework" and "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework" I was able to make the connection.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: yepp this is the right provider, the Nuget site says: *This NuGet package is for ODP.NET, Managed Driver applications that use Code First and/or **Entity Framework 6** applications.*